# Primefaces subTable in dataTable not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

i am pretty new to jsf and i'm having a bit trouble implementing a subTable in my dataTable. Der var atribute from my subtable doesn't seem to evaluate to the elements from the list. Also the @PostConstruct method from my backing bean isn't called either, when i execute my webapp and navigate to the xhtml site. No errors are shown in the console, so i have pretty much no idea what i did wrong.

**Backing Bean**

```
@Named(value = "selfEvalBean")
@ViewScoped
public class SelfEvaluationBean extends AbstractBean implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 310401011219411386L;


private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SelfEvaluationBean.class);

@Inject
private ISelfEvaluationManager manager;


private List<SelfEvaluation> selfEvaluations;


private SelfEvaluationTopic topic;


public List<SelfEvaluation> getSelfEvaluations() {
    return selfEvaluations;
}


public void setSelfEvaluation(final List<SelfEvaluation> theSelfEvaluations) {
    selfEvaluations = theSelfEvaluations;
}


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        return;
    }
    final User user = getSession().getUser();
    List<SelfEvaluation> eval = user.getSelfEvaluations();
    if (eval == null) {
        eval = manager.createSelfEvaluation(user);
    }
    selfEvaluations = eval;
    topic = new SelfEvaluationTopic();
}

//some methods

/**
 * @return the topic
 */
public SelfEvaluationTopic getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

/**
 * @param theTopic
 */
public void setTopic(final SelfEvaluationTopic theTopic) {
    topic = theTopic;
}



}
```

**SelEvaluation Class**

```
@Entity
public class SelfEvaluation extends JPAEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

@Column
private String title;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<SelfEvaluationTopic> topics = new ArrayList<>();


public User getUser() {
    return user;
}


public void setUser(final User theUser) {
    user = theUser;

public List<SelfEvaluationTopic> getTopics() {
    return topics;
}


public void setTopics(final List<SelfEvaluationTopic> theTopics) {
    topics = theTopics;
}


public void addSelfEvalTopic(final SelfEvaluationTopic theTopic) {
    topics.add(theTopic);
}


public void removeSelfEvalTopic(final SelfEvaluationTopic theTopic) {
    topics.remove(theTopic);

}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object theObject) {
    if (!(theObject instanceof SelfEvaluation)) {
        return false;
    }
    final SelfEvaluation other = (SelfEvaluation) theObject;
    return getId().equals(other.getId());
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(final String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId().hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("SelfEvaluation {id: %d, from: %s}", getId(),
            user.getUsername());
}

}
```

**SelfEvaluationTopic Class**

```
@Entity
public class SelfEvaluationTopic extends JPAEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String topic;

@Column
private boolean sad;

@Column
private boolean normal;

@Column
private boolean happy;


public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
}


public void setTopic(final String theTopic) {
    topic = assertNotNull(theTopic);
}


public boolean getSad() {
    return sad;
}


public void setSad(final boolean evaluation) {
    sad = evaluation;
}


public boolean getNormal() {
    return normal;
}


public void setNormal(final boolean evaluation) {
    normal = evaluation;
}


public boolean getHappy() {
    return happy;
}


public void setHappy(final boolean evaluation) {
    happy = evaluation;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object theObject) {
    if (!(theObject instanceof SelfEvaluationTopic)) {
        return false;
    }
    final SelfEvaluationTopic other = (SelfEvaluationTopic) theObject;
    return getId().equals(other.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId().hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String
            .format("SelfEvaluationTopic {id: %d, topic: %s, sad: %b, normal: %b, happy: %b}",
                    getId(), topic, sad, normal, happy);
}

}
```

**XHTML Site**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="templates/template.xhtml"> 
    <!--header and footer template-->
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:loadBundle basename="internationalization.selfEval" var="msg" />
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:growl id="info" autoUpdate="true"  />

            <p:dataTable id="selfEval" var="eval" value="#{selfEvalBean.selfEvaluations}" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    #{msg['header']}
                </f:facet>
                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">#{msg['selfEval']}</f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column width="2%">
                            <f:facet id="sad" name="header">
                                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="sad.png"/> 
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column width="2%">
                            <f:facet id="sad" name="header">
                                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="normal.png"/> 
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column width="2%">
                            <f:facet id="sad" name="header">
                                <p:graphicImage library="images" name="happy.png"/> 
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>                      
                </p:columnGroup>

                <p:subTable var="t" value="#{eval.topics}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{eval.title}" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column id="topic" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{t}" /> <!--t is of type List<SelfEvaluation> and not SelfEvaluationTopic-->
                        <p:commandButton style="float:right; width:22px; height: 22px; background-color: #cd001e;" title="Delete" update=":form" action="#{selfEvalBean.remove(t)}" icon="fa fa-trash-o" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column width="2%" >
                        <div style="text-align: center;" >
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="s" value="#{t}"  />
                        </div>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column width="2%"  >
                        <div style="text-align: center;" >
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="n" value="#{t}"  />
                        </div>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column width="2%" >
                        <div style="text-align: center;" >
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="h" value="#{t}" />
                        </div>
                    </p:column>
                </p:subTable>
            </p:dataTable>

                <center>
                    <p:commandButton id="addSelfEvalTopic" styleClass="button" value="#{msg['actionAdd']}" onclick="PF('evalDialog').show();" update=":form" />
                    <p:commandButton id="selection" styleClass="button" style="float:right;" value="#{msg['actionSelect']}" action="#{selfEvalBean.save}" />
                </center>


        </h:form>
        <p:dialog widgetVar="evalDialog" header="#{msg['newTopic']}" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" resizable="false">
            <h:form id="dialog">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Description:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{selfEvalBean.topic.topic}" required="true" maxlength="60" />

                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['actionSave']}" styleClass="button"  action="#{selfEvalBean.addTopic}" update=":form" oncomplete="PF('evalDialog').hide();" />
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['actionCancel']}" styleClass="button"  immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('evalDialog').hide();" /> 
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Manager Class fills the Database with some initial data, so there is nothing really interesting going on.
JSF version is 2.2.12 and PrimeFaces version is 6.0.
I'm using Maven for build and the webapp is running on GlassFish 4.1.1.

Comment: are you using weld for CDI? remove `<h:form id="buttons">`. Nested forms do not work!! I don't understand why you have a `List<SelfEvaluation>` inside your subTable or why your @PostConstruct method isn't being called. Try removing the nested form first. Maybe that helps

Comment: Removing the forms didn't help :(

Comment: The User class has a     List<SelfEvaluation> and each SelfEvaluation Object has his own List<SelfEvaluationTopic> and i want to diplay each SelfEvaluationTopic. Every SelfEvaluation Object should have it's own SubTable.

Comment: I see that the table is pretty much like the one in primefaces' showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml. I don't understand the problem. I'll try it out later.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar In Glassfish 4.1.1 he should have the Mojarra implementation 2.2.13 of JSF actually.

Comment: yes i'm using the mojarra implementation version 2.2.12, i'm sry about that. Exactly i don't understand it either, i actually also researched some other examples for p:subtable and every page i found pretty much referenced the primefaces page (witch is obvious, because it's their component)

Comment: Could you show the template? And I guess there are no clues in the log when the server starts? Try deleting from the xhtml and see if problem is still there with a minimal example